# How should I implement "Forgot your password" in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, membership

I'm using the standard SqlMembershipProvider that comes with the ASP.NET MVC demo.

I'm interested in implementing a "Forgot your password" link on my site.

What is the correct way for this feature to be implemented?  Should I overwrite the password with a temporary one and email it to their registered email?

Answer (score 10):

Based on the nature of the application, the Best practice for the forgot password should be in following order

1. Allow the user to verify the **Secret/Question** for a maximum of 3 to 5 attempts
2. On successful validation, Send an e-mail with **random generated password** with a validity of 24hrs.
3. The e-mail must contain **only the password** but not both username/password.
4. When user logs in with temporary password, then user must be forced to **create a new password** before going to home page.

Answer (score 8):

The provider will automatically do the reset for you:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.resetpassword.aspx

The sample just returns the new password to the browser instead of emailing the user but uses the secret question / answer that can be configured with the provider.

This sample gets the password and emails it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlmembershipprovider.getpassword.aspx

I think either approach is safe.  The email it step is a bit safer since the user will have to know the question/answer and email password to hack an account.

I realize these samples are not using MVC but I am sure it's enough to get you going. :)

Answer (score 5):

Surely it is better to email the user a link with some sort of impossible to guess URL (say containing a random Guid. When the user clicks the URL they are able to reset the password. The URL should be good for one use only, and should expire after a set time.

Answer (score 5):

It depend what type of membership provider you are using. 
But I will recommend using simple membership provider for authentication for more detail 
[please visit the following link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx)

Here is some code for you

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordModel model)
    {
      .
      .
      .  
      .
                if (WebSecurity.UserExists(model.UserName))
                {
               var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(model.UserName, 60);
                  .
                  .
                  .
                  .                        
                    // send this token by email
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not find User");
                }
            }
      return View(model);


    }

 [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult ResetPassword( ResetPasswordModel model)
    {
        string token = Request.Params["token"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
        {
            if (WebSecurity.ResetPassword(token, model.NewPassword))
            {
        // send email…….. or                                          
                return View();
            }
        }
```